# app.get and app.post get value in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using the `app.get` and `app.post` functions in Express on Node.js.

I have examples like this:

```
app.post('/status', function(req, res) {
  if (~packages.STATUSES.indexOf(req.body['status'])) {
    res.status(req.body.status, req.body.message);
    res.jsonp(new packages.Success('status updated'));
  } else {
    res.jsonp(new packages.Error('invalid status'));
  }
});
```

This will work if I post the data to the sever, and I noticed that it gets the value by

```
req.body['status'];
```

What if I use GET and  pass the value here? What should I do to get the 'status'?

```
app.get('/status', function(req, res) {
// how can I get status... var status = ??
  if (~packages.STATUSES.indexOf(status) { //got value
    res.status(req.body.status, req.body.message);
    res.jsonp(new packages.Success('status updated'));
  } else {
    res.jsonp(new packages.Error('invalid status'));
  }
});
```

Sorry if it sounds dumb but I did some research and couldn't find any examples online. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `req.query.status` or `req.query['status']` for GET requests.

Comment: @jackhao -- No problem, not sure why the down vote, ill even ya out :). Be sure to accept the answer once it allows ya!

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly suggest to use

```
req.param('status') //
```

it [looks up](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param) req.body/req.query as well as req.params, so with this you can map all three below routes to the same method

```
app.get('/status',statusHanlder);
app.post('/status', statusHanlder);
app.get('/status/:status', statusHanlder)

var statusHanlder = function(req, res){
  var status = req.param('status')
}
```